# Was Bane's destiny pre-plotted?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises, character

It's of no doubt that Talia was the mastermind behind the plan and Bane her executor. Did she plan for Bane to be sacrificed(*if needed*) for the successful execution of the plan?

I ask this question because towards the end Talia asks Bane to keep Batman alive so that he can "**feel the heat**" and also bids "**Goodbye my friend**" to Bane, kind of implying that he was to meet his end too with Batman.

Comment: Not in the Comics. Bane (like any Superhero or Villain) is destined to come back again and again and again. This video should help you understand Bane's backstory: http://www.comicvine.com/3-minute-expert-who-is-bane/112-1425/

Comment: As far as i can remember, she was driving the truck with bomb in it. So she was also sacrificing herself for successful execution of the plan. So why would she care anymore about Bane's life. It was a suicide mission either way

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Considering the fact that they were mere moments from being in the blast radius of a nuclear explosion, I can confidently argue that neither Talia nor Bane expected to get out of this situation alive, and that their eventual death was part of their plan.

This sequence is merely Talia and Bane recognizing that, if their plan comes to fruition, that moment will be the last they see of each other.  Also from the looks of the plan, Talia was merely leaving to ensure the bomb will go off and that no last minute rebellion from the police, military, or whatever stragglers remains would interfere.

Obviously they both failed in their overall plan and met their demise regardless, just not in the way they hoped.

Comment: That seems like a perfectly plausible explanation! But then m thinking, why was Bane going to shoot Batman and disregard Talia's instruction. Was it because he was plain mad because he had been *handed his ass* by the Batman moments ago or he had a way out and no intention of *feeling the heat* himself.......

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher I think Bane disobeying Talia in moving to shoot Batman was a nice nod to his capabilities as a baddie by not falling into the old [Bond Villain Stupidity](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BondVillainStupidity) trope. He knew that Batman was too dangerous to be kept alive.

Comment: and that would sum it up perfectly! @IrrelevantElephant if I may suggest, why dont you answer the question.....the way you see it.....

Comment: @KeyBrd Basher Nice of you to say but I would mostly just be reiterating TylerShads. I agree completely with his answer.

Answer (score 0):

There mission behind the attack on Gotham city by both Talia and Bane was to, like Ras-Al-Ghul thought, perish the city as corruption in the city went too far for correction. So they planned to attack with nuclear bomb, so that nobody could escape alive from Gotham. The only problem in front of the success of their plan was the Batman. So to make sure the bomb goes off as planned, they chose not to leave the city. Here the psychology of Suicide Bomber sometimes matches with the attitude of them. They knew from the start if they stay in the city they will die like @tyler pointed out, the blast radius is too big for anybody to escape from it. But they also wanted to made it a success, which Batman could hamper. So they decided to rather stay. So we can conclude that they wanted to stay and die for the reason.  She loved him and wanted him to join her for the noble (!) cause.

As far as Talia is concerned, I don't think she wanted to leave the city alone or sacrifice Bane. You see, Talia had the trigger to blast the bomb and she did not try to escape while pressing it. Its because of Gordon's try the bomb did not went off then. She did not merely use Bane for the success of the plan.

I think Bane joined her just because they loved each other and he also wanted to join Talia for the so called "noble" reason (Don't forget he was also the disciple of Ras-al-Ghul). So they knew they were going to die. Bane beat Batman because he was angry on him like any criminal should be. He also wanted to make sure that Batman passes away as early as possible, because there is nothing more stupidity than keep ones enemy alive. After all we cant deny he was an A-1 criminal. That is why before Talia left him she bid the last **Good Bye** to her protector cum lover Bane.

Comment: I never implied that Talia had plans to flee. In my comment to *@TylerShads'* answer I suggested that **Bane** might have such plans...... But again, thats just *speculation* on my part.....

Comment: To that, I can only say, from what I have interpreted, Bane did not want to leave too....And I have cited the reasons in the last paragraph. He loved Talia and joined the cause knowing he might have to die.

Comment: One little detail of this answer strikes me as odd is that Ra's had planned a suicide bomber technique too, but I disagree.  The Emitter was planned to vaporize the water, causing Gotham to riot itself into destruction, it wsa implied to me that Ra's merely stayed with his men to ensure the emitter hit its destination, and then be off, no intention of dying with the city.

Comment: @Tyler,I did not mean to say anywhere in my answer that Ra tried to do a suicidal bomb attack. If it seemed to you,you may cite the part, I will correct it.

Comment: Ah, I read it wrong, the first sentence made it sound like he meant to "perish with the city" my apologies.